# How can we validate just the mandatory fields in a form in SAP UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create a form which has some mandatory fields that requires validation on form submission.

Could anyone suggest me the best possible way to do that in SAP UI5? The mandatory fields are in greater number, thus i don't want to check all fields separately by their ID.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two scenarios. While entering a value, or when submitting the form as in your question.

```
CheckRequired: function(oEvent) {


            var aInputs = [this.getView().byId(oEvent.getSource().getId())];
            var sError = false;

            jQuery.each(aInputs, function(i, input) {
                if (!input.getValue() || input.getValue().length < 1) {
                    input.setValueState("Error");
                    input.focus();
                    sError = true;
                } else {
                    input.setValueState("None");
                }
            });
            return sError;

        },
```

This function is to be used with the onLiveChange property. It checks if the control is filled with at least one character.

If you would like to check everything when you press submit. you could use a function like this with your form:

```
_onSubmitCheck: function() {
        var oForm = this.getView().byId("form").getContent();

        var sError = false;

        oForm.forEach(function(Field) {
            if (typeof Field.getValue === "function") {

                if (!Field.getValue() || Field.getValue().length < 1) {
                    Field.setValueState("Error");

                    sError = true;

                }
                else {
                    Field.setValueState("None");
                }

            }

        });
        return sError;

    },
```

It will loop over your form controls to check if the getValue() method exists as part of the control. If that returns yes, it wil check if it has a value of at least 1 character.

Answer (score 2):

There are kind of two ways.

Add

```
"sap.ui5": {
...
    handleValidation": true,
```

to your manifest.json and then add type & constraints to your inputs:

```
<Input 
    type="Text" 
    value="{path: 'NoFioriValidationsInDefault', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String', constraints: { minLength:2 }}" 
    valueLiveUpdate="true" enabled="{= ${editView>/nfvid/enabled} &amp;&amp; ${editView>/creating}}" 
    visible="true" 
    width="auto" 
    valueHelpOnly="false" 
    maxLength="0" 
    id="inp_cond_nfvid" 
    required="{editView>/nfvid/required}"/>
```

This gives just visual feedback to the user, if you need the status in your controller you can either iterate over all the inputs and check them by hand, or use [UI5 Validator](https://github.com/qualiture/ui5-validator).

Just by calling

```
var validator = new Validator();
validator.validate(this.byId("form1"));

if (!validator.isValid()){
  //do something additional to drawing red borders? message box?
  return;
}
```

in your controller, the view will mark missing required inputs with the ValueState.ERROR (red borders) and tell you if all inputs inside the supplied control are valid.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing it the old-school way. The input fields do get the `required=true` property and then I loop over all controls found with this property:

```
// store view ID to compare with control IDs later
var viewId = this.getView().getId();
jQuery('input[required=required]').each(function () {
    // control has wrapper with no id, therefore we need to remove the "-inner" end
    var oControl = sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.id.replace(/-inner/g,''));
    // CAUTION: as OpenUI5 keeps all loaded views in DOM, ensure that the controls found belong to the current view 
    if (oControl.getId().startsWith(viewId) && (oControl instanceof sap.m.Input || oControl instanceof sap.m.DatePicker)) {
        var val = oControl.getValue();
        if (!val) {
            oControl.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
            oControl.openValueStateMessage();
            bError = true;
            return false;
        } else {
            oControl.setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
            oControl.closeValueStateMessage();
        }
    }
});
```

HTH,

Anton